# Растет потребление памяти

Tags: c#, .net, память

Не могу *разобраться* почему утекает память в приложение (winform, .net). Использую для распознава́ния текста GdPicture.Net, за один цикл (около 200 вызовов функции из GdPicture.dll) в целом прирастает на 20 Мб. Вот данные с профилировщика VisualStudio. первый момент времени и второй.
[image: условно первый момент времени]

[image: условно второй момент времени]

Функция с выделением наибольший памяти выглядит вот так(**никак**)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Куда копать не знаю, в коде *вроде бы* работаю аккуратно, везде где нужно реализовал интерфейс IDisposable. Даже не знаю что конкретно выложить из кода, для того чтобы разобраться. Буду рад любой помощи.

```
   public class OCRReader : IDisposable
{
    private  GdPictureImaging oGdPictureImaging = new GdPictureImaging();
    private  int m_ImageID;

    //[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "ShellExecuteA")]
    //private static extern int ShellExecute(int hwnd, string lpOperation, string lpFile, string lpParameters, string lpDirectory, int nShowCmd);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (oGdPictureImaging == null)
            return;
        oGdPictureImaging.OCRTesseractClear();
        oGdPictureImaging.Dispose();
    }
    public  string ImageProccessing(int sourceX, int sourceY, int distinationX, int distinationY, int quality, bool saveImg = false, string name = "Empty")
    {
        try
        {
            LicenseManager oLicenceManager = new LicenseManager();
            oLicenceManager.RegisterKEY("0429254382496276761391972");
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(distinationX, distinationY))
                {
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, distinationX, distinationY);
                    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp as Image);
                    graphics.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
                    bmp.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    if (memory != null)
                    {
                        if (GdPictureDocumentUtilities.GetDocumentFormat(memory) == DocumentFormat.DocumentFormatPDF)
                        {
                            GdPicturePDF oPDF = new GdPicturePDF();
                            if (oPDF.LoadFromStream(memory) == GdPictureStatus.OK)
                            {
                                m_ImageID = oPDF.RenderPageToGdPictureImageEx(200, true);
                                if (m_ImageID == 0)
                                    return "File could not be loaded. Error: " + oPDF.GetStat().ToString();
                                oPDF.CloseDocument();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            m_ImageID = oGdPictureImaging.CreateGdPictureImageFromStream(memory, DocumentFormat.DocumentFormatJPEG);

                            if (m_ImageID == 0)
                                return "Image could not be loaded. Error: " + oGdPictureImaging.GetStat().ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    if (oGdPictureImaging.Scale(m_ImageID, quality, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic)
                        != GdPictureStatus.OK)
                        return "Error: " + oGdPictureImaging.GetStat().ToString();

                    string sOCR = null;
                    int ncpt = 0;
                    int LeftArea = 0; int TopArea = 0;
                    OCRContext context = OCRContext.OCRContextSingleLine; 
                    oGdPictureImaging.OCRTesseractSetOCRContext(context);
                    if (oGdPictureImaging.OCRTesseractReinit() != GdPictureStatus.OK)
                    {
                        return "Error" + " " + oGdPictureImaging.GetStat().ToString();
                    }
                    sOCR = oGdPictureImaging.OCRTesseractDoOCR(m_ImageID, "eng", "OCR\\", "");

                    if (oGdPictureImaging.GetStat() == GdPictureStatus.OCRDictionaryNotFound)
                    {
                        return "Needed dictionary is not into the specified path!";
                    }
                    else
                    {


                        oGdPictureImaging.OCRTesseractClear();

                        return sOCR;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }}
```

Ну и вызов пусть примерно вот так проходит

```
 using (OCRReader ocr = new OCRReader())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    var val0 = ocr.ImageProccessing(100+i, 292, 53, xdestination, 220);

                }
            }
```

Касательно этого примера, чем больше i, тем больше памяти выделяется за один цикл.

Comment: Одно дело реализоваит интерфейс в своем классе, другое правильно пользоваться его методами в коде приложения.

Comment: То, что тип реализует ```IDisposable``` не означает, что захваченный ресурс будет освобожден сборщиком мусора.

Comment: @tym32167 везде где я использую объект этого класса, заключаю его в "using" на сколько я знаю, это и означает что вызовется Dispose. Или  не так?

Comment: Если везде заключаете в ```using```, то ```Dispose``` да, должен вызываться.  Но вообще есть "правильный" пример реализации на MSDN https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dependency-properties Это я так, для справки, а в чем у вас проблема я не имею понятия.

Comment: Сборка мусора в .NET недетерминирована. Нельзя говорить об утечке между двумя итерациями цикла. Утечка - это когда потребление памяти продолжает расти на протяжении длительного времени, и что-то не дает сборщику мусора эту память освободить.

Comment: И да, IDisposable не имеет никакого отношения к освобождению управляемой памяти (памяти, выделенной под объекты). IDisposable - это способ контроля неуправляемых ресурсов (хэндлов открытых файлов, например). С точки зрения рантайма IDisposable ничем не отличается от других интерфейсов и его реализация на сборку мусора и освобождение памяти никак не влияет.

Comment: Из кода - выкладывайте минимальный пример для воспроизведения проблемы. Такой, который при каждом вызове будет отъедать память, и не освобождать ее на протяжени длительного времени.

Comment: Рекомендую подцепиться к приложению dotMemory и снять несколько снапшотов, растянутых во времени. Если утечка есть, они это покажут. Прислушайтесь к @PashaPash, сборщик мусора не обязан освобождать память немедленно, равно как и она не обязана переходить из StandBy во FreePool, пока не понадобится другим приложениям.

Comment: @PashaPash выложил пример.

Comment: `using (Graphics graphics = ...`. `GdPicturePDF ` - это что?  `if (memory != null)` - это зачем?

Comment: @Igor это скриншот области экрана в Bitmap, который потом сохраняется в memory

Comment: Я указал, где у Вас утечка ресурсов, и задал два вопроса. Вы о чем?

Comment: @Igor вы имеете ввиду что нужно обернуть в using ( Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp as Image))?  GdPicturePDF oPDF = new GdPicturePDF(), в эту строчку на практики никогда не попадает, так как не работаю с PDF.  if(memory!= null) не удалил с того момента как вставил using на menory, те это не зачем

Comment: @YuryBakharev "нужно обернуть в using" - да.

Comment: @Igor "нужно обернуть в using" - да.  Это не помогло.

Comment: Возьмите профайлер памяти (dotMemory, или обычный профайлер студии), сделайте snapshot до вызова, потом snapshot после вызова, сравните их и посмотрите, кто ссылается на объекты, выедающие память.

Comment: @PashaPash oGdPictureImaging от этот объект. У него несколько методов Clear оказывается,  "один из них сработал" . Смутило, что на офф. сайте в примере вызывается тот, что в коде " oGdPictureImaging.OCRTesseractClear();", а нужен   oGdPictureImaging.ClearGdPicture(); Никакие using именно в этом методе не являются причиной.